# Web API 2 modify db in GET method

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-sql, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2

I want to modify some fields after query, but the return value is changed after I modified the fields.

I want to keep the IQueryable value after I modify it.

How can I store the IQueryable value?

```
public IQueryable<Book> GetBook(int id)
    {
        IQueryable<Book> Books = null;
        IQueryable<Book> Book_return = null;

       Books = db.Book.Where(u => u.id == id && u.is_read != true);

        Book_return = Books;

        foreach (var item in Books)
        {

            item.read_time = DateTime.Now;
            item.is_read = true;
            db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
        }

        try
        {
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
        {
            throw;
        }

        return Book_return;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
IEnumerable<Book> Book_return = null    
Book_return = Books.ToList();
```

And the return type of the method must be a `IEnumerable<Book>`,

Comment: `IEnumerable<Book> Book_return = null;`
`Book_return = Books.ToList();`

Comment: @Sha-PaiLi You are off course right. But you should also change the return type of your action.